# Typescript Http request send form data

Tags: typescript, multipartform-data

I want to send form-data. But request has no body attribute.
How can I use request to send form-data?

```
import { request } from 'http';

const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', FILE);

const req = request(
                {
                    host : HOST,
                    port : '80',
                    method : 'POST',
                    path : PATH,
                    headers : form.getHeaders(),        
                },
                response => {
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly the http library in node is really low level and not super friendly to use. I'd consider looking at something like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) because it's much friendlier as a developer.

If you're set on using http, then the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) are useful, in particular for you [request.write](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestwritechunk-encoding-callback) is the method you're looking for.

Those same docs from nodejs provide [worked examples](https://nodejs.dev/learn/make-an-http-post-request-using-nodejs) for a post with either axios:

```
const axios = require('axios')

axios
  .post('https://whatever.com/todos', {
    todo: 'Buy the milk'
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`)
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

or http:

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Buy the milk'
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'whatever.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```